# C# enum, double previous enum value

Tags: c#, enums

I've come across something which appears strange to me, but at the same time makes some sense for reasons I don't know.

I have this enum:

```
[Flags] public enum Flags { RemoveQuoteMarks = 1, t1 = 2, t2 = 4, t3 = 8, t4 = 16, t5 = 32, t6 = 64, t7 = 128 }
```

Before, I didn't manually set the enum values, they index from 0 and standardly increase by 1 right?

Well I noticed odd behavior when I tried to load this string:

```
string value = "t1, t3, t4, t7";
```

and parse it using:

```
Flags flags = (Flags)Enum.Parse(typeof(Flags), value);
```

and the result was just 't7', so I did some research, and noticed a lot of others used manual indexing where each enum value was doubled by its previous (e.g. 't3 = 8', 't4 = 16'), so I applied this rule to mine, and it worked, my parsed enum had now shown as:

```
t1, t3, t4, t7
```

as desired, why do I have to manually configure my enum values like that?

Comment: because its using bitwise `|` operator. if you dont modify values like that it will be like `1 | 3 | 4 | 7` which will result in `7`. because 7 is `111` in binary and will eat all the other values ;)

Comment: Read the answer to the duplicate, especially the "under the covers" section.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I feel like I understand a lot better now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you need this is that the flags enum is represented as a binary number.  Each value that is a power of 2 (1,2,4,8,16 etc.) corresponds to a different index in the binary number:

- `2 ->   10`
- `4 ->  100`
- `8 -> 1000`

This is essential so that you can determine which flags a given value actually contains.  For instance if your class has an enum value of `1110` it has the flag values of 2,4 and 8.

If you use values that are not powers of 2, c# can no longer reasonably distinguish which enum values are represented by your classes flags when performing bitwise and `&`.